# Extract data from two tables and order by date

Tags: mysql

I have two seperate tables:
**Table1 -** id, news, date_added
**Table2 -** id, news, extra, date_added

Is it possible to query both table and extract data ORDER BY date_added
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
select id, news, date_added,"" as extra
from table1
union all
select id, news, date_added,extra
from table1
ORDER BY date_added
```